# Builtin function to replace all occurences of a value in a given column with value from column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes in PySpark say A, B whose structures looks like below. I want to update value in a column of Dataframe A with lookup values found in Dataframe B. Is there an inbuilt function in PySpark to achieve this or do I have to recursively run `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace`?

```
DataFrame A               Dataframe B             Resultant
---------------           ---------------       --------------- 
| seqn | colB |           | colX | colY |       | colA | colB  |  
---------------           ---------------       ---------------
| s1   | x,y,z|           | p    | c    |       | a    | e,f,g |
| s2   | p,y,r|  takes    | r    | d    |  ==>  | a    | c,f,g |
| s3   | y,z  |  value    | x    | e    |       | a    | f,g   |
| s4   | p,z  |  from     | y    | f    |       | a    | c,g   |
---------------           | z    | g    |       ---------------- 
                          ---------------
```

Comment: you will need to join the two dataframes